# Jackson - List of abstract reference can't be deserialized

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've got a problem with the Jackson library and I'd like to have your help on a specific point.

I managed to reproduce my problem within an isolated test case. It has to do with Jackson not being able to deserialize a list of abstract reference when there is a real object behind the reference.

#### Code that is not working

```java
public class TestListOfAbstractRef {

        public interface TestInterface {}

        @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
        public static class Root {
            public String id;
            public Root(){}
        }

        @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
        public static class Test1 extends Root implements TestInterface {
            public String test1_param = "test1_param";
            public Test1(){}
        }
        public static class Test2 extends Root implements TestInterface {
            public String test2_param = "test2_param";
            public Test2(){}
        }

        public static class Test3 extends Root{
            public Test3(){}
            @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
            public List<TestInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Test
        public void TestListOfAbstractRef_SerializationAndDeserialization() throws IOException {
            Test1 test1 = new Test1();
            test1.id = "#1";
            Test2 test2 = new Test2();
            test2.id = "#2";
            Test3 test3 = new Test3();
            test3.id = "#3";
            test3.list.add(test1);
            test3.list.add(test2);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
            String test3_string = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new Object[]{test1,test2,test3});
            Object[] objects = objectMapper.readValue(test3_string, Object[].class);
        }

}
```

#### Result of the serialization

```
[ {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test1",
  "id" : "#1",
  "test1_param" : "test1_param"
}, {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test2",
  "id" : "#2",
  "test2_param" : "test2_param"
}, {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test3",
  "id" : "#3",
  "list" : [ "#1", "#2" ]
} ]
```

#### Error produced by jackson

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `TestListOfAbstractRef$TestInterface` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (String)"[ {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test1",
  "id" : "#1",
  "test1_param" : "test1_param"
}, {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test2",
  "id" : "#2",
  "test2_param" : "test2_param"
}, {
  "@class" : "TestListOfAbstractRef$Test3",
  "id" : "#3",
  "list" : [ "#1", "#2" ]
} ]"; line: 12, column: 14] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][2]->TestListOfAbstractRef$Test3["list"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:265)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithObjectId(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1257)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:192)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:193)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:21)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004)
    at TestListOfAbstractRef.TestListOfAbstractRef_SerializationAndDeserialization(TestListOfAbstractRef.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:515)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:131)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:153)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:167)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:146)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:93)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

### How to fix this problem ?

I found two way to fix this problem

#### 1°) Replace the TestInterface in the list by the Root class

```
    public static class Test3 extends Root{
        public Test3(){}
        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        public List<Root> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

There is no more problem in this case since the Root interface isn't an abstract element and it can be constructed. But that's not a solution more a workaround.

#### 2°) Change the default typing to NON_FINAL and save Test3 as a whole file without the id reference

```
public class TestListOfAbstractRef {


    public interface TestInterface {}

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static class Root {
        public String id;
        public Root(){}
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
    public static class Test1 extends Root implements TestInterface {
        public String test1_param = "test1_param";
        public Test1(){}
    }
    public static class Test2 extends Root implements TestInterface {
        public String test2_param = "test2_param";
        public Test2(){}
    }

    public static class Test3 extends Root{
        public Test3(){}
        public List<TestInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void TestListOfAbstractRef_SerializationAndDeserialization() throws IOException {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        test1.id = "#1";
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        test2.id = "#2";
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
        test3.id = "#3";
        test3.list.add(test1);
        test3.list.add(test2);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        String test3_string = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(test3);
        Test3 test31 = objectMapper.readValue(test3_string, Test3.class);
    }

}
```

This way everything is in the file, the type information as well and there is no problem for Jackson to deserialize the elements.

## Danger

Why am I asking for help when I found a solution ?

Simple, this class pattern isn't really mine to speak grossly, in fact it's the result of a script that I made that generate those classes and this pattern, I can't really change the way it is because this pattern is correct and correspond to what I want translate. What I'm asking is solution to serialize and deserialize this kind of pattern.

Do you have any idea on how to do so ?

---

## Edit

Found an another workaround for the problem, simply create a custom deserializer for the interface (or the absract class) that is incriminated. In this deserializer resolve the reference by yourself using the objectidresolver within the context. This solution is really not elegant but does the trick. In my case, it means that I need to auto generate a custom deserializer for every interface that I have. I feel like this is a really big effort for such a simple thing...

```
public class TestListOfAbstractRef {

    public static class TestInterfaceDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<TestInterface> {

        protected TestInterfaceDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
            super(vc);
        }

        protected TestInterfaceDeserializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        @Override
        public TestInterface deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            ReadableObjectId roid = ctxt.findObjectId(p.getText(), new PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator(Object.class) ,new SimpleObjectIdResolver());
            return (TestInterface) roid.resolve();
        }
    }

    public interface TestInterface {
    }

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public static class Root {
        public String id;

        public Root() {
        }
    }

    public static class Test1 extends Root implements TestInterface {
        public String test1_param = "test1_param";

        public Test1() {
        }
    }

    public static class Test2 extends Root implements TestInterface {
        public String test2_param = "test2_param";

        public Test2() {
        }
    }

    public static class Test3 extends Root {
        public Test3() {
        }

        @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
        public List<TestInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void TestListOfAbstractRef_SerializationAndDeserialization() throws IOException {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        test1.id = "#1";
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        test2.id = "#2";
        Test3 test3 = new Test3();
        test3.id = "#3";
        test3.list.add(test1);
        test3.list.add(test2);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(TestInterface.class, new TestInterfaceDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

        String test3_string = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new Object[]{test1, test2, test3});
        Object[] objects = mapper.readValue(test3_string, Object[].class);
    }

}
```